# Celery: Parent job and other tasks in a group hang when maximum retry of a task is reached

Tags: python, celery, celery-task, flower

I have celery tasks, grouped together, which hang when one task in the group reached the maximum number of retries.

I'm just raising exceptions in the body of the tasks (i.e. unpack and validate) because I'm still experimenting the tasks' retry feature.

Here's the code:

```
@app.task(name='job', bind=True, queue='job')
def process_job(self, job_type, params):
    res = None
    ret = {"job_status":"SUCCESS", "job_message":"job_process_done"}
    res = group(unpack.s(params["s3_location"]), 
          validate.s(params["s3_location"]))()
    return res.get()

@app.task(name='unpack', bind=True, queue='unpack', max_retries=3, 
          default_retry_delay=1*10)
def unpack(self, s3_location):
    ret = {"unpack_status":"SUCCESS", "unpack_message":"unpack_done"}
    try:
        raise Exception("")
    except Exception, ex:
        if unpack.request.retries == unpack.max_retries:
            raise Exception('UNPACK: Max Retries Reached')
        else: unpack.retry(args=[s3_location])
    return ret

@app.task(name='validate', bind=True, queue='validate', max_retries=4, 
          default_retry_delay=1*10)
def validate(self, s3_location):
    ret = {"validate_status":"SUCCESS", 
           "validate_message":"validate_done"}
    try:
        raise Exception("")
    except Exception, ex:
        if validate.request.retries == validate.max_retries:
            raise Exception('VALIDATE: Max Retries Reached')
        else: validate.retry(args=[s3_location])
    return ret
```

When the max retry of validate task was reached, the other task (unpack), as well as the parent task (process_job) were not completed. That is, their states were stuck to 'RETRY' and 'STARTED' respectively. Below are the snapshot images:

**1. Flower showing job states**

[image]

**2. Celery worker in terminal showing the max number of retries were was reached**

[image]

**3. Validate detailed status in flower**

[image]

**4. Unpack detailed status in flower**

[image]

How to fix the unfinished tasks issue? Am I doing something wrong in my tasks code/implementation?

Answer (score 0):

For those who have encountered this same issue, I was able to resolve this by making the gap of the max_retries of each task, at least, to 2 (i.e. max_retries=3 for unpack, max_retries=5 for validate). By doing this, the retry attempt of the other task is going to be executed and caught in the try-catch block.

Hope this helps!